# print multiline textbox data of crystal report for 270 degrees rotated text

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Hello i want to print multi line text object, my text object is set 270 degrees rotation that's why can grow option is disable, is there any others way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Wraping field in crystal report](https://sochinda.wordpress.com/2009/10/07/wraping-field-in-crystal-report/)

1. Open CRYSTAL REPORT
2. Open The The Open The Report That You Want To Enable Word Wrap Report
3. Right Click On The Field That You Want To Word Wrap.
4. Select Format Object
5. Then Place A Check In The Box Can Grow and set the maximum line number.

Comment: my text object is set 270 degrees rotation that's why can grow option is disable, that means my text vertical text.